# how to solve "nametuple" cant be found in module "collections"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

im running python 3.7 I'm trying to create a file that works as an operator for a loginpage.py i made but when i run the operator.py file it gives a lot of errors  but it doesn't specify the problem the one problem specified is AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'namedtuple'

I've tried running it in an env made by pycharm
checked on all syntax possible everything looks good
i tried to run in pything 2.2 thru 3.6 not working

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class OperatorWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class OperatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return OperatorWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    oa = OperatorApp()
    oa.run()

#code ends here

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/OneDrive/Udemy/My own apps/pos/operator/operator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 10, in <module>
    import fnmatch
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\fnmatch.py", line 14, in <module>
    import re
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 125, in <module>
    import functools
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter, eq as _eq
  File "D:\OneDrive\Udemy\My own apps\pos\operator\operator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 316, in <module>
    from inspect import getfile
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\inspect.py", line 35, in <module>
    import dis
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\dis.py", line 184, in <module>
    _Instruction = collections.namedtuple("_Instruction",
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'namedtuple'
```

the expected from this is to open a windows called operator it will be blank but it wont open it

the error message i put it in with the code above

Answer (score 3):

Calling your module `operator` was not a good choice.
It shadows a module in the standard library.

The key difficulty is that `import operator`
now won't pull in the usual functions.

Consider pushing everything down one level,
so you access your module as `myapp.operator`
rather than just `operator`.
Alternatively, you might rename to `operator1.py`,
or rename the `operator` directory.

Comment: In this case the error can be found by noticing that the stdlib function imports a user module, and the circular import.

Comment: @J_H  now it ran perfect the window operator pop up showed and everything is back to normal. I appreciate the help. Thanks a lot!